# Symfony - FOS UserBundle Error: "Attempted to load class 'User' from namespace..." by opening the /register Page

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I'd like to use the Fos UserBundle in Symfony.

I've configure it like "Getting Started With FOSUserBundle" from Symfony Doc.

The /Login Page is working but when I open the /register Page I get the Error:

> Attempted to load class "User" from namespace "AppBundle\Entity".
>    Did you forget a "use" statement for e.g. "Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User", "Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Tests\Fixtures\User" or "FOS\UserBundle\Model\User"?

```
500 Internal Server Error - ClassNotFoundException 

Stack Trace

1. in vendor\friendsofsymfony\user-bundle\Model\UserManager.php at line 40  
37.    public function createUser()
38.    {
39.        $class = $this->getClass();
40.        $user = new $class();
41.
42.        return $user;
43.    }

2. at UserManager ->createUser  ()
```

I've cleared the caches:

```
php app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-warmup
php app/console cache:clear --env=dev --no-warmup
```

and made a composer update but nothings happened.

**Versions:**

- FOS/user-bundle: v2.0.0
- Symfony: v2.8.18
- PHP: 7.1.2
- Twig: v2.3.0

Here ist my user-class:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * web_user
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="web_user")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\web_userRepository")
 */
class web_user extends BaseUser

{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You forgot to change the user_class in your config.yml file.

Try `user_class: AppBundle\Entity\User` or similar.

Comment: THX, 
you're right... I forgot to set the correct class name in the config.yml under fos_user / user_class

Answer (score 0):

Symfony 4, create file:
config/packages/fos_user.yaml

```
fos_user:
  db_driver: orm
  firewall_name: main
  user_class: App\Entity\User
  from_email:
      address: "mail@mail.com"
      sender_name: "Sender Name"
```

Info:

https://vfac.fr/blog/how-install-fosuserbundle-with-symfony-4