# Symfony4 - Error while visting /register page

Tags: php, symfony, xampp, fosuserbundle

I am using [FOSUserBundle](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/index.html) with Symfony4. 
When trying to visit `/register` url, I am getting this error message:

```
Attempted to load class "User" from namespace "AppBundle\Entity".
Did you forget a "use" statement for e.g. "Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User", "Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Tests\Fixtures\User" or "FOS\UserBundle\Model\User"?
```

Another SO user posted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43206013/symfony-fos-userbundle-error-attempted-to-load-class-user-from-namespace) question, but the suggested answer still not working in my case.

Here is the code for `User.php` class.

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;


/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // your own logic
    }
}
```

And here for `config/packages/fos_user.yaml`

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: AppBundle\Entity\User
```

Here is the `RegistrationController` code related to `register` action. (note: this is auto-generate code, I have not changed anything)

```
/*
 * This file is part of the FOSUserBundle package.
 *
 * (c) FriendsOfSymfony <http://friendsofsymfony.github.com/>
 *
 * For the full copyright and license information, please view the LICENSE
 * file that was distributed with this source code.
 */

namespace FOS\UserBundle\Controller;

use FOS\UserBundle\Event\FilterUserResponseEvent;
use FOS\UserBundle\Event\FormEvent;
use FOS\UserBundle\Event\GetResponseUserEvent;
use FOS\UserBundle\Form\Factory\FactoryInterface;
use FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserEvents;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcherInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\SessionInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException;

/**
 * Controller managing the registration.
 *
 * @author Thibault Duplessis <thibault.duplessis@gmail.com>
 * @author Christophe Coevoet <stof@notk.org>
 */
class RegistrationController extends Controller
{
    private $eventDispatcher;
    private $formFactory;
    private $userManager;
    private $tokenStorage;

    public function __construct(EventDispatcherInterface $eventDispatcher, FactoryInterface $formFactory, UserManagerInterface $userManager, TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage)
    {
        $this->eventDispatcher = $eventDispatcher;
        $this->formFactory = $formFactory;
        $this->userManager = $userManager;
        $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
    }

    /**
     * @param Request $request
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function registerAction(Request $request)
    {
        $user = $this->userManager->createUser();
        $user->setEnabled(true);

        $event = new GetResponseUserEvent($user, $request);
        $this->eventDispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_INITIALIZE, $event);

        if (null !== $event->getResponse()) {
            return $event->getResponse();
        }

        $form = $this->formFactory->createForm();
        $form->setData($user);

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted()) {
            if ($form->isValid()) {
                $event = new FormEvent($form, $request);
                $this->eventDispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_SUCCESS, $event);

                $this->userManager->updateUser($user);

                if (null === $response = $event->getResponse()) {
                    $url = $this->generateUrl('fos_user_registration_confirmed');
                    $response = new RedirectResponse($url);
                }

                $this->eventDispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_COMPLETED, new FilterUserResponseEvent($user, $request, $response));

                return $response;
            }

            $event = new FormEvent($form, $request);
            $this->eventDispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_FAILURE, $event);

            if (null !== $response = $event->getResponse()) {
                return $response;
            }
        }

        return $this->render('@FOSUser/Registration/register.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }
}
```

And Stack Trace:

```
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException:
Attempted to load class "User" from namespace "AppBundle\Entity".
Did you forget a "use" statement for e.g. "Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User", "Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Tests\Fixtures\User" or "FOS\UserBundle\Model\User"?

  at vendor\friendsofsymfony\user-bundle\Model\UserManager.php:40
  at FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManager->createUser()
     (vendor\friendsofsymfony\user-bundle\Controller\RegistrationController.php:59)
  at FOS\UserBundle\Controller\RegistrationController->registerAction(object(Request))
     (vendor\symfony\http-kernel\HttpKernel.php:149)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(object(Request), 1)
     (vendor\symfony\http-kernel\HttpKernel.php:66)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(object(Request), 1, true)
     (vendor\symfony\http-kernel\Kernel.php:190)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle(object(Request))
     (public\index.php:37)
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Show us your controller. I suspect you forgot to add use statement for User bundle on top of the controller.

Comment: I don't know where is the related controller. I just followed this article (https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/index.html), and there is nothing about controller. May be, it is being created automatically, can you tell me where could I find controller so I can paste that code here.

Comment: Aha, Controller logic is done when you import routing for FOS Bundle. I'm assuming you did that. Is there any other place you used your User class?

Comment: Below the error message there should be a stack trace showing where the error happened.

Comment: I did not use User class anywhere else, I just followed the article, and next only thing i trying to visit register page, and getting this error.

Comment: Yes. RegistrationController, with register action method, code is posted in question.

Comment: Please could you add the stack trace to your question (if it's too big at least the part in red).

Comment: @Philippe-B- Stack trace added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using Symfony 4 which doesn't have bundles by default, it stores entities in the `src/Entity` directory.

The error comes from the namespace in your User class that you probably copied.
Try setting the namespace of your class to `App/Entity`.

Comment: I changed namespace in User.php as "namespace App\Entity;"...and also in fos_user.yaml as "user_class: App\Entity\User"...then it works.